# Mosquitto C++ Client on Raspberry PI not recieving messages

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, mosquitto

I'm trying to use mqtt on my raspberrpi4.
I installed mqtt and the c++ headers.

I start my broker with :

```
mosquitto -d
```

Then for a validation I start a client via the command line:

```
mosquitto_sub -d -t "test"
```

Then I also start the c++ client (following code):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mosquitto.h>

char mqMsg[30];

void my_message_callback(struct mosquitto *mosq, void *userdata, const struct mosquitto_message *message)
{
    if(message->payloadlen){
        printf("BANANA %s %s\n", message->topic, message->payload);
    }else{
        printf("BONONO %s (null)\n", message->topic);
    }
    fflush(stdout);
}

void my_connect_callback(struct mosquitto *mosq, void *userdata, int result)
{
    int i;
    if(!result){
        mosquitto_publish(mosq, NULL, "hello/world", strlen(mqMsg), mqMsg, 2, 0);
    }else{
        fprintf(stderr, "Connect failed\n");
    }
}

void my_log_callback(struct mosquitto *mosq, void *userdata, int level, const char *str)
{
    /* Pring all log messages regardless of level. */
    printf("%s\n", str);
}

void my_publish_callback(struct mosquitto *mosq, void *userdata, int usernumber)
{
    /* We've published so lets exit nicely */
    mosquitto_disconnect(mosq);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    char *host = "localhost";
    int port = 1883;
    int keepalive = 60;
    bool clean_session = true;
    struct mosquitto *mosq = NULL;

    sprintf(mqMsg,"%s",argv[1]);
    printf("And the word is >> %s <<\n", mqMsg);

    mosquitto_lib_init();
    mosq = mosquitto_new(NULL, clean_session, NULL);
    if(!mosq){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Out of memory.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    mosquitto_log_callback_set(mosq, my_log_callback);
    mosquitto_connect_callback_set(mosq, my_connect_callback);
    mosquitto_message_callback_set(mosq, my_message_callback);
    mosquitto_publish_callback_set(mosq, my_publish_callback);

    if(mosquitto_connect(mosq, host, port, keepalive)){
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to connect.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    mosquitto_loop_forever(mosq, -1, 1);
    mosquitto_subscribe(mosq, NULL, "test", 2);
    while(1){
    }

    mosquitto_destroy(mosq);
    mosquitto_lib_cleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

After that I publish something on the topic

```
mosquitto_pub -d -t "test" -m "test message"
```

I can see the message on the command line client but not on the c++ client?

Any idea why?

B.t.w. publishing via the c++ client works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You call `mosquitto_subscribe(mosq, NULL, "test", 2);` after `mosquitto_loop_forever()`, therefore when your client actually runs, it's not subscribed to your topic. This also means that you don't need the `while(1)` in your code. See https://mosquitto.org/api/files/mosquitto-h.html#mosquitto_loop_forever for the description of the `mosquitto_loop_forever()' function.

Comment: but does the program not exit without the while loop? or does it still run but in a background loop? but how can I stop it then after the program exists?

Comment: Your program will not exit without the while loop, as the  `mosquitto_loop_forever()` will actually block (think of it as it also has a `while(1)` loop in it). The `mosquitto_loop_forever()` will return only when you call `mosquitto_disconnect()` from one of your callback functions. To exit the program, you can send a signal (for example SIGINT by pressing CTRL-C in the terminal where you run it). If you want to do the needed cleanup (you should!), then register a handler function for SIGINT, and call the `mosquitto_disconnect()` from that handler.

Comment: See for exampe this tutorial on signal handlers: https://linuxhint.com/signal_handlers_c_programming_language/

Comment: thank you very much! putting the subscription before the loop and removing the disconnect inside the pub_callback did the trick!:) thanks